# Where to put converting PDF function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-reducers

I have the following scenario:

1. send API request with contract id as a payload when clicking download contract button
2. get the pdfBuffer field in API response
3. have a **fuction A** which can convert pdfButtfer to pdf file

in index.js under Actions

```
export const fetchContract = contractId => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .post('/view-contract', { contractId: contractId })
      .then(res => {
        const pdfBuffer = res.data.pdfBuffer
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
};
```

Can we directly invoke **function A** in index.js under Actions folder or we need to dispatch the pdfBuffer to reducer and get the pdfBuffer from container component which connects to redux store and then invoking **function A** at container component level?

Please advise. thanks a lot.